# Where to put setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

I have a working slider. I would like to to autoplay the slides and stop the autoplay when user clicks the next or previous button.

I have tried to include setInterval-function but I am not sure how I should apply it in order to make it work. So far I did not manage to do this.

enter code here

```js
var interleaveOffset = 0.2;

var swiperOptions = {
  loop: true,
  speed: 500,
  grabCursor: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  mousewheelControl: true,
  keyboardControl: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  },
  on: {
    progress: function() {
      var swiper = this;
      for (var i = 0; i < swiper.slides.length; i++) {
        var slideProgress = swiper.slides[i].progress;
        var innerOffset = swiper.width * interleaveOffset;
        var innerTranslate = slideProgress * innerOffset;
        swiper.slides[i].querySelector(".slide-inner").style.transform =
          "translate3d(" + innerTranslate + "px, 0, 0)";
      }      
    },
    touchStart: function() {
      var swiper = this;
      for (var i = 0; i < swiper.slides.length; i++) {
        swiper.slides[i].style.transition = "";
      }
    },
    setTransition: function(speed) {
      var swiper = this;
      for (var i = 0; i < swiper.slides.length; i++) {
        swiper.slides[i].style.transition = speed + "ms";
        swiper.slides[i].querySelector(".slide-inner").style.transition =
          speed + "ms";
      }
    }
  }
};

var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", swiperOptions);
```

I expect that slider plays the slides automatically and the autoplay stops when user clicks either next or previous button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `autoplay`

```
autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: true,
},
```

`disableOnInteraction` will disable autoplay when you will click on arrows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to apply the autoplay in the end of the javaScript but nothing happens. Is there some specific place on the code where I should put it? *Edit: Actually when I place the autoplay in the end the buttons dont work anymore.

Comment: Hey! This appeared to be the closest correct answer. I just needed to apply the autoplay: true; to the swiper options and now it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From top of my head you can use something like this

```
let timer = null

const startSwiping = () => {
 timer = setInterval(() => {
   swiper.slideNext(100); // transition duration (ms) as argument
 }, 500)
}

const stopSwiping = () => clearInterval(timer)
```

I did not try that but Swiper docs dont show any other option than `swiper.slideNext(speed)`

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it still wont autoplay.

Comment: I'm sorry, change `setTimeout` to `setInterval` and `clearTimeout` to `clearInterval`. Timeout will just fire once. And if you need to start playing just call function `startSwiping()`. When you want to stop than call `stopSwiping()`